# Adding a header to any webpage I want

Tags: php, html, header

I researched the internet and haven't found anything about this so I come requesting your help  Stack Overflow community.

What I want to learn/find out is how to use a form input where I post a link to any website and after clicking the submit button, it takes me to that website with a header coded by me on it on my domain (similar to StumbleUpon).

I got the HTML/PHP part down so all that remains is the "2nd" page with the website from the input and my header in it. I don't want anything fancy for the header so I'm just gonna do a plain HTML text and style it with a bit of CSS. What I don't know is how to put the rest of the website under it.

Comment: HTML frames. Google for that.

Comment: Are you refering to HTML framesets? If so I heard they are no longer recommended, is that true?

Comment: They are very 90's yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hunch but before just answering your question, I did some research. It seems that stumbleupon uses iframes to load the page under the toolbar. Here is a link to StumbleUpon staff answering a question about that.

http://www.quora.com/Does-StumbleUpon-use-iframes-to-load-other-pages-If-so-how-do-they-get-around-scripts-that-bust-out-of-frames

Answer (score 1):

It's an HTML feature called frames. An example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="80,*">
<frame src="your-header.html">
<frame src="http://theotherwebsite.com/">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot believe someone is still using frames

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all fancy, you can pull in the content dynamically and display it using something like cURL.

```
<?php

print "HTML STUFF HERE FOR HEADER<br><br>";

$url = 'http://www.cnn.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

print $data;
```